# Evaluating a triple integral by inspection

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I would like to evaluate the triple integral:

$$\iiint\limits_D {2 + 3{x^2} + 3{y^2}dV}$$

where $D$ is a conic domain with vertex $(0,0,b)$ and axis along the $z$-axis with a base (disk) with radius $a$ in the $xy$-plane

**My working:**

Since integration is a linear operation, we get:

$$2\iiint\limits_D {dV + 3\iiint\limits_D {{x^2} + {y^2}dV}}$$

The first part represents the volume of the domain, hence $2\times1/3\times a^2b\pi$ (formula for volume of a cone).

The second part is a bit tricky. It seems like we could change variables, but this is where I am stuck.

Does anyone know how to find the value of the second integral?

**Edit: Using substitution (cylindrical coordinates)**

$$3\iiint\limits_D {{x^2} + {y^2}dV} = 3\iiint\limits_{D'} {{r^3}drd\theta dz} = 3\int_0^b {dz} \int_0^{2\pi } {d\theta } \int_0^a {{r^3}dr = a{b^3}\pi /6} $$

Unfortunately, the answer suggests $$\frac{3}{{10}}\pi {a^4}b + \pi {a^2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $x^2+y^2\, dV = r^2\,r\,dr\,d\theta\,dz=r^3\,dr\,d\theta\,dz$ in polar coordinates

**Solution:**

[image]

This is the cone. It's equation is $r=a-\frac abz$. You need to parameterize the bounds of the integral. It will be:

$$2 \pi  \int _0^b\int _0^{a-\frac{a z}{b}}r^3drdz=\frac{1}{10} \pi  a^4 b$$

Which, when you multiply by 3, you get the suggested answer. And I think you already know the other integral.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I attempted to use cylindrical coordinates (as can be seen in my answer), but it does not seem to give me the right answer :(. Do you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Artem Solved it.